# плавное исчезновение объектов при скролле?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать так, чтобы при сролле черного блока постепенно(пока скролишь) исчезали вверх logo, sublogo, text и link, пока не появился зеленый блок.
Как на этом сайте https://toyfight.co/who/ . Тут код: https://jsfiddle.net/qagz4vwe/22/ . Спасибо

```js
window.addEventListener("load", readyScript);
function readyScript() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', elTravel);

    let srcProcent;

    let go = true;

    function elTravel() {
        let pageScreens = document.querySelectorAll('.sectors__slide');

        for (let index = 0; index < pageScreens.length; index++) {
            const pageScreen = pageScreens[index];
            const pageScreenTop = pageScreen.getBoundingClientRect().top + scrollY;
            const pageScreenHeight = pageScreen.offsetHeight;

            if (pageScreen.classList.contains('main-block')) {
                let blockTypes = document.querySelector('.main-block__content');
                let mainBlock = document.querySelector('.main-block');
                let mainBlock_2 = document.querySelector('.main-block-2');
                srcProcent = (scrollY - pageScreenTop) / pageScreenHeight * 100;
                if (scrollY > pageScreenTop && scrollY < pageScreenTop + pageScreenHeight) {
                    let blockTypesSlide = scrollY - pageScreenTop;
                    blockTypes.classList.add('_fixed');
                    blockTypes.style.cssText = `transform: translate(0px,${blockTypesSlide}px);`;
                } else if (scrollY <= pageScreenTop) {
                    blockTypes.style.cssText = `transform: translate(0px,0px);`;
                    blockTypes.classList.remove('_fixed');
                    mainBlock.style.cssText = `opacity: 1; min-height: 100vh; `;
                    mainBlock_2.style.cssText = `opacity: 1;min-height: 100vh;`;
                } else if (scrollY >= pageScreenTop + pageScreenHeight) {
                    blockTypes.style.cssText = `transform: translate(0px,${pageScreenHeight}px);`;
                    blockTypes.classList.remove('_fixed');
                    mainBlock.style.cssText = `opacity: 0; min-height: 0;`;
                    mainBlock_2.style.cssText = `opacity: 0; min-height: 100px; `;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

    function onResize() {
        go = true;
        elTravel();
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);

    elTravel();

}
```

```css
.sectors__content {
    background: #161616;
}

.main-block {
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

.main-block__content {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 590px;
    height: 100vh;
}

.main-block__center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.main-block__logo {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 55px;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.main-block__sublogo {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 44px;
}

.main-block__text {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 34px;
}

.main-block__link {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.green-block {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    min-height: 590px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectors__content">
    <div class="sectors__slide main-block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main-block__content">
                <div class="main-block__center">
                    <div class="main-block__logo">
                        ЛОГО
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-block__sublogo">sublogo</div>
                    <div class="main-block__text">text</div>
                    <a href="" class="main-block__link"><span>button</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sectors__slide main-block-2"></div>
    <div class="sectors__slide green-block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onEntry(entry) {
    entry.forEach(change => {
      if (change.isIntersecting) {
       change.target.classList.add('element-show');
      }
    });
  }
  
  let options = {
    threshold: [0.5] };
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(onEntry, options);
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element-animation');
  
  for (let elm of elements) {
    observer.observe(elm);
  }
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.element-big  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
}

.element-animation {
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  min-height: 590px;
  /* Скроем элемент в начальном состоянии */
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.element-animation.element-show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1.5s;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="element-big green"></div>
    <div class="element-animation">
      <span>Элемент, который появляется</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Можно так.
Источник: https://webgolovolomki.com/poyavlenie-elementov-pri-skrolle/